# Crystal Report Group sort formula

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have set the group sort formula and it is working fine, but every time the report runs it ask for the value for the parameter, I already have a field in my report which holds the sort value, I want to set parameter value to this field but no success, every time a prompt appears and I have to write the Sort Value again and then it is working.

```
if{?Sort}="Mortgage Advisor Ascending"
then 
crAscendingOrder else crDescendingOrder
```

Any way out by which I can set the value to this field?
Do I have to write a formula to set this field to this parameter as well? If yes how and where?
My formula for equating is:

```
{ActiveApplicationsReportDT.SortField} = {?Sort}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer to the same, that I must pass some value of the parameter from the code itself, so I was passing the Sort order in a query string and then I was setting the parameters by splitting the query string, so I just gave one sort parameter from the same in my Report parameter and now work is done.

```
ParameterFields Fields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterField ItemFd= new ParameterField();
ItemFd.ParameterFieldName = "NewParameter"; 
ParameterDiscreteValue DItemFd = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
DItemFd.Value = SortOrder;// this a sort parameter
ItemFd.CurrentValues.Add(DItemFd);
Fields.Add(ItemFd);
```